# Namespaces and subnamespaces in C#

Tags: c#, namespaces

begginers question about C#.

In every program I have to include several namespaces, like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
```

Why do I have to include:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
```

... since they are included with first one:

```
using System;
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You don't **have** to **include** any namespaces at all.
It does not include anything into the assembly, it merely makes the classes in the namespace accessable from the global namespace. All the names are resolved to their fully qualified names at compile-time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because nested namespaces are not included with parent one. See [using directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) documentation for details

> A **using** directive does not give you access to any namespaces that are nested in the namespace you specify.

Comment: But I can run same program without last three

Comment: Because those three namespaces contain extensions that are likely to be useful: Generic collections (e.g. `IEnumerable<int>`), [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/bb397926.aspx) extensions and text processing utilites. Actually, you dont' even need `System` for the application to run, hovewer there aren't much use of such an application (you can't even output anything, since `Console` class is in `System` namespace)

Comment: @user198003 Visual studio puts them there by default because they contain frequently used classes. If you don't need them you can remove them. Either way it does not affect the resulting assembly in any way.

Comment: Yes, you can. IDE adds few most frequently used namespace in the new Console Application to facilitate first steps.

Comment: If you can run a program without the last 3, then it's because you're not using anything that's included in the last 3.  E.g. you're not using any Linq commands, Generic lists or System.Text classes/methods.

Comment: @user198003 that is because you are not using any features of those 3 namesapaces.If you create a new class those will be there by default, try using StringBuilder, a linq query and you might not  be able to run that.

Comment: I often find myself renaming "System.Linq" to "System.IO" because more often I use the latter and not the former. Saves a little bit of typing.

Answer (score 2):

`System` and `System.IO` namespaces are different.

You can treat "subnamespace" as parent-child relationship in the object model. If you have access to the "Car" object does not mean that you have access to car's wheels.

`System` is a huge namespace that contains hundreds of nested namespace and thousands of classes. You should specify all nested namespaces separately to state what part of the module are you interested in.

Answer (score 2):

`System` and `System.Text` are two different namespaces. That `System.Text` seems to be a part of `System` is the semantics we as programmer put into it. There's no such thing as a nested namespace from a platform view;

But even if that was not the case what should happen if you had

```
namespace MySystem{
   namespace Foo{
       class Bar {...}
   }

   class Bar{...}
}

using MySystem;
class MyClass{
    private Bar _myBar; //Which one is it MySystem.Foo.Bar or MySystem.Bar?     
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Imagine these namespaces with these classes (the last name is a class):

- `A.B.Class1`
- `A.Class2`

**Now you have the following:**

`using A`  - allows you to refer to Class2 directly... but not to Class1.

`using A.B` - allows you to refer to Class1 directly but not to Class2.

If you want to refer to both classes directly in your code, you need both usings.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're beginner let me clarify one thing `namespace` in C# and `package` in Java are different things. no need to merge them.

Answer (score 0):

Not all classes in .net is inside one big container.Doing so increases the chance of class name collision and it doesn't look good in the first place.Namespaces are containers that try to keep your library clean and make more sense.Having a FTP class and String class together under one container does not logically make any sense.They do two different things and they should be kept in separate containers.

Also a namespace can be nested.Sometime A namespace can all but have just another namespace,without any class.so to access a class you need to qualify the full namespace before you can use it.

In your case you use different classes ,which are on different containers.So if you need them you need to qualify them with their namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Just an added example to make you understand clearly.

A child Namespace cant be accessed by calling parent namespaces

```
Namespace Main  //only code and classes are accessible
{
  //code for Main Namespace
  Namespace subMain     //only code and classes are accessible
  {
     //code for subMain
     Namespace verySubMain  //only code and classes are accessible
     {
        //code for verySubMain
     }
     Namespace otherVerySubMain  //only code and classes are accessible
     {
        //code for otherVerySubMain
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: And could you please explain how this ansewers the question?

Comment: @J0HN this doesnt answer the question, it is just an example to make OP understand clearly. As I mentioned in my post.

Answer (score -1):

If you wanted access to a class in System.Text without the using statement, you would have to Text."Name of class/function" every time you wished to use it.

This way you can just call "name of class/function".

Not sure if you are a beginner, but that's the simplest way I can describe put it.

Comment: Namespaces can not contain functions.

Comment: I know, but I meant a function from within a class in that namespace.